# Should I use MAAS and Juju if I only intent to use a single PC?

Tags: juju, maas

I am planing to setup a local server at my home that I will use for various entertainment/work tasks. Do you think that installing MAAS and juju is an overkill if I intent to use only one pc?

Comment: @Memelaos What do you mean with overkill? If you mean overload; then perhaps adding specs. you plan to setup would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for one machine MAAS is absolutely overkill.

However Juju can (as of version 1.18) deploy to any Ubuntu Server with OpenSSH via manual provisioning, we designed this feature for cases like yours where you want to deploy services quickly without needing a cloud:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-manual

The basic process is you register your machine(s) with Juju via: `juju add-machine ssh:10.1.1.2` for example. And then you can deploy services to your one server (preferably in LXC containers to keep them isolated).

If you had racks and racks of machines then MAAS makes sense, if you have one box or a handful of machines then the manual provider is much simpler to get up and running.

See also:

- [Is juju only for cloud usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97148/is-juju-only-for-cloud-usage)